# Custom Paypal field on button

Tags: paypal

I need to include a custom field when PayPal notifies me of a payment.
I'm trying to use the advanced variables, but I don't see a way that I can make them dynamic.

Pretend I have a field "xyzzy" with a value of "plugh".  I would like PayPal to include form.xyzzy=plugh with all the other fields that it sends to my notify_url.

Of course, the value of xyzzy might be "foo", depending upon what they user wants.

Comment: I have a field in the html form called custom with a value of 2 and an advanced variable in paypal, custom=1.  When I examine the custom value in the notify_url, it is equal to 1, but I need it to be equal to 2.

Comment: Nice reference to Colossal Cave Adventure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's only "custom": input type="hidden" name="custom" value="plugh"

This is returned in the [IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn/) message as well.

Comment: can we send more than one custom field?