# Extra Custom field add for success page. in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

i have need multiple extra field add on return page. But i could only one field passing and getting . my code is:-

```
 <form class="validate" id="paypalform"  method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
                            <h3>Amount :- $5.99</h3>

                            <p class="mc-field-group clearfix">
                               Email : <input required class="required email mce_inline_error" id="mce-EMAIL" name="custom" type="email" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
                            </p>

                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="er.XXX@gmail.com">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Closer t">
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">

                            <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="54.99">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://website.com/aypal-notcompleted/">
                            <input name="notify_url" value="http://website.com/paypal-ipn/" type="hidden" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                            <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_id" value="fffff"/>

                            <div class="btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" >
                                    Paynow
                                </button>
                            </div>         
         </form>
```

on success.php page

```
 echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_GET);
   die;
```

Output :-

```
Array
(
    [tx] => 7KC790518W762915S
    [st] => Pending
    [amt] => 5.99
    [cc] => USD
    [cm] => asheesh9308@gmail.com
    [item_number] => 1
)
```

But i want geting also invoice_id on success page

Comment: My problem same as well as:- please give me anyone solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833192/custom-paypal-field-on-button