# GetTransactionDetails without transaction id

Tags: php, paypal

I have website where I use PayPal NVP sandbox. Sometimes after successful payment of user, PayPal get back to my return URL very slow. Unless PayPal returns to my website with details I am unable to check whether user has completed the order (For all attempt website adds order id to the database) or not and that destroys website's work principle.

What I need is that I want to retrieve the data of transaction without transaction id if possible. Maybe with custom field or something else. If I would be able to check the transaction details without transaction id , then I would be able to handle the requests by user accordingly. Or if there is a way to get a transaction id somehow with the help of another variable that also fine as I will make checking after finding out the transaction id.

Comment: Relying on the return URLs to match the transaction is dangerous: users could close the browser, they could take too long to come back. You should rely on [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/) or [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/) to retrieve the completed transactions and update your database/users accordingly. Depending on your implementation you can pass custom variables to the PayPal buttons (e.g. userId or OrderId). [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833192/custom-paypal-field-on-button) as an example

Comment: I am using IPN. The address I have put for IPN gets complete details. But the problem is about the delay. Details of transaction is sent by paypal might take some time. I explained in my first message

Comment: The delay shouldn't affect your flow. Make the user wait (e.g. with a loading) until IPN is received and you matched the data. Also note that sandbox is slower than production. So while you should still account for delays, it'll get better un prod.

Comment: I can’t change the flow, it is a instant deal website, so the seconds matter. + if the website is down for that time for some reason then data will not be sent to the website second time. So flow destroyed. There should be a way to make a request to get the transaction id or retreive the data without transaction id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current PayPal Checkout integrations give an immediate response of success/failure. There is no need for any redirect away from your site, and there is no need to wait for asynchronous IPN or webhook messages. Don't use such things.

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'; you can use the Checkout-PHP-SDK).  Both of these routes on your server should return/output only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: the only problem here is that the integration guidlines you mentioned is Javascript however I would live to use PHP instead.

Comment: The code that runs in the browser will be HTML and JS. For the server-side API calls you can use the Checkout-PHP-SDK, or implement your own HTTPS functions.

Comment: what about complete usage of Checkout-PHP-SDK ? I have actually integrated the Checkout-PHP-SDK it forwards to the page where I change the amount and etc.. and forward to the PayPal then once user pays PayPal returns to my website and I make checking. But the logic still becomes the same as NVP I think. Because if user closes the browser immediately once the payment is successful then I am again unable to get the details. Or even he returns back to website Transaction id is still not visible.

Comment: I need to check the transaction manually in that case.. at least I can get the transaction by using the link : `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8GB67279RC051624C`

Comment: Do not redirect away from your site. Use the JS approval flow, which will call your server. Your server will call the PayPal API to capture the order, and receive an immediate response of success or failure (directly from PayPal) along with the transaction ID. The browser is not involved until later (forwarding the response object so it can display success/failure/restart accordingly)

Comment: I think you are absolutely right, I should do exactly what you said. And once I use JS  will I be able to get transaction id for future processes? for example I often use capture method and later I send the request to PayPal to complete the transaction. Or for refunds I also will need that maybe.

Comment: When the payer approves the payment in the browser, `onApprove` is called, and this calls your server to complete the transaction -- by capturing the order, generally, though it's also possible to integrate with intent:authorize and authorize the order, if you need that.  Regardless, the resulting completed order will have a capture id or authorization id that you can then store in your system's order record, and do whatever you need to do with it in the future using the separate v2/payments API

Comment: I have completed the integration as you said, thank you.. But one question I have in my mind. What if the user closes IMMEDIATELY the browser  before the `onsuccess` processes completed?

Comment: Either the order is captured by your server, or it isn't. If it isn't, there is no transaction.

Comment: wow, this is the best part I love this JS SDK probably. It makes the control checking very easy..Thank you very much..